# Boolean in React read as undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I have backend and db isUrgent type as boolean. In React, I have some code for frontend which works perfectly for getting the boolean data to db and backend, but the frontend reads that data as undefined. Why is that? :

```
 this.state = {
        id: this.props.match.params.id,
        name: '',
        offerCost: ' ',
        isUrgent: ' ',
```

(...)

```
this.changeUrgentHandler = this.changeUrgentHandler.bind(this);
```

(...)
componentDidMount(){

```
    if(this.state.id === 'add'){
        return
    }else{
        OfferService.getOfferById(this.state.id).then( (res) =>{
            let offer = res.data;
            this.setState({
                name: offer.name,
                offerCost: offer.offerCost,
                isUrgent: offer.isUrgent,
```

(...)

```
saveOrUpdateOffer = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let offer = {
        name: this.state.name,
        offerCost: this.state.offerCost,
        isUrgent: this.state.isUrgent,
```

(...)

```
<div className = "form-group">
<label> Urgent</label>
<input placeholder="isUrgent" name="isUrgent" className="form-control"
value={this.state.isUrgent} onChange={this.changeUrgentHandler}/>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably because here it does not exist: OfferService.getOfferById()

Comment: but it does exists. OfferService uses axios to get it from backend. I works fine with name and offerCost. Only problem is with isUrgent.

Comment: So is Urgent is returned by your axios response? Maybe share this on an online code sandbox, mocking the data.

Answer (score 0):

you should check
`this.props.match.params.id` not undefined first. because
first time react component load it will be undefined

Comment: I understand that at start everything is undefined, buy why afterwards name and offerCost are read as defined and isUrgent is still undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have manage to fix it. To those who have the same problem: I don't know why, byt when I have change my backend getter name from "isUrgent" to "getIsUrgent" it works fine. I still don't understand why......